# I have converted a pdf file to csv using anaconda python3 But the converted csv file is not in a readable form how to make it readable?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pypdf

```
# importing required modules 
import PyPDF2 

# creating a pdf file object 
pdfFileObj = open(path, 'rb') 

# creating a pdf reader object 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 

# printing number of pages in pdf file 
print(pdfReader.numPages) 

# creating a page object 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 

# extracting text from page 
print(pageObj.extractText()) 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(pdfFileObj)
print (df)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I have converted a pdf file to csv using anaconda python 3. But the converted csv file is not in a readable form.  how to make that csv in readable format?

Comment: _But the converted csv file is not in a readable form. _ What does that mean, specifically? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your method and I couldn't find a way to correct the csv ouput. I useally do it this way:

```
import csv
import os
from miner_text_generator import extract_text_by_page
def export_as_csv(pdf_path, csv_path):
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_path))[0]
    
    counter = 1
    with open(csv_path, 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
            text = page[0:100]
            words = text.split()
            writer.writerow(words)
            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_path = '<your path to the file>.pdf'
    csv_path = '<path to the output>.csv'
    export_as_csv(pdf_path, csv_path)
```